# Rounding a Value in the WPF Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm attempting to implement a progress bar with a textbox on top that also displays the progress %.  However the percentage is fractional.  Is it possible to round a value returned in the dataset via the binding or does it have to be done via the code behind?

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="5,5,5,2" Name="pbProgressIndex" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Value="{Binding Path=ProgressIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="25" Name="txtProgressIndex" Text="{Binding Path=ProgressIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="Auto" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Verdana" Padding="5" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) Property of the Binding, eg.:

```
{Binding Path=ProgressIndex, Mode=OneWayToSource, StringFormat=N2}
```

The `N2` formatting can also be specified the following way:

```
{}{0:N2}}
```

Comment: I ended up modifying the dataset to round the value when it was coming in and then using:
     Text="{Binding Path=ProgressIndex, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0}%}"

Comment: The string format should be "N2", the format specifier (letter) needs to come first. See .NET docs on standard format strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 5):

```
StringFormat={}{0:#.00}
```

it looks better to me;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the StringFormat in Femaref's answer you need to get rid of the `Mode=OneWayToSource` settings. That mode is for pushing values from a control to a bound object (like a ViewModel) without receiving updates made to the value from code, which is the opposite of what you're trying to do. You want the OneWay mode for these which happens to be the default for both the TextBlock.Text. ProgressBar.Value used TwoWay by default, which will still work fine in this case, but you can also set it to `Mode=OneWay`.

Comment: Good call.  I caught it before coming back to see the answer (YAY! copy and paste), but +1 for the attention to detail.